# How to build a insert query using key value pair

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a insert query that uses all the textboxes names (the keys so to speak in `KeyValuePair<>`) so I will not have to type out all the named parameters (ie the textboxes name) but instead just use all of the textboxes names from the list.

My code is as follows:

```
private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (members.DBConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\qbc.mdb"))
    {
        members.DBConnection.Open();

        // find out which textboxes were filled out
        foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                members.textBoxes.Add(new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>(((TextBox)ctrl).Name, ((TextBox)ctrl).Text));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < members.textBoxes.Count; i++)
        {
                members.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(String.Format("@{0}", members.textBoxes[i].Key),
                       !string.IsNullOrEmpty(members.textBoxes[i].Value) ? members.textBoxes[i].Value : "");
        }

        using (members.DBCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO members (fullName, birthday, phoneNumber, address, email, status, anniversary)" +
                    "VALUES(@" + members.textBoxes + ")", members.DBConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                members.DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
         }
    }
 }
```

But when I try to use `members.textBoxes.Key` (on the using `members.DBCommand` line, it is giving me an error:

```
 List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method named 'Key' accepting a first argument of 'List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
```

I would really prefer not to type out all the names of the textboxes in the VALUES part of the query, if there is a way to do that.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Update -

I have changed my code to so it follows some answers given

```
 private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // associate the textboxes with the column fields in the database
        // long but meh
        // household head textboxes
        textBox_hh.Tag        = "fullName";
        textBoxHHBirthday.Tag = "birthday";
        textBoxPhone.Tag      = "phoneNumber";
        textBoxAddress.Tag    = "address";
        textBoxEmail.Tag      = "email";
        textBoxStatus.Tag     = "status";



        using (members.DBConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\qbc.mdb"))
        {
            members.DBConnection.Open();

            // find out which textboxes were filled out
            foreach (var textbox in Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                 var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(textbox.Tag.ToString(), textbox.Text);

                 members.textBoxes.Add(pair);
            }

            var columnNames = string.Join(", ", members.textBoxes.Select(m => m.Key));

            var parameterNames = string.Join(", ", members.textBoxes.Select(m => $"@{m.Key}"));

            var query = $"INSERT INTO members ({columnNames}) VALUES ({parameterNames})";



            using (members.DBCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, members.DBConnection))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var member in members.textBoxes)
                    {
                        members.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{member.Key}", member.Value);
                    }

                    members.DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException ex)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                   return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but unfortunately the query now is just `INSERT INTO members () VALUES ()`

Comment: Exception message pretty clear. `members.textBoxes` is collection of key-value pairs, so property `Key` should be used only on the item of that collection `members.textBoxes[0].Key`

Comment: Looks like you are trying to magically have your list of KeyValuePairs somehow magically fill in your values.  This is leaving you open to an SQL injection attack.  Your code is also adding parameters before you create your command object.  Whatever is happening in this god "members" class looks like spaghetti code from here.

Comment: This line seems odd `"VALUES(@" + members.textBoxes + ")"` where `members.textBoxes` is a collection.

Comment: yes I know @Fabio, I was unsure of how to use it to make parameters with the key value pair as no property was available after .textBoxes

Comment: The main problem that I can see on your code is the lacking of type for the parameters that you are adding. For example a DateTime value is prone to serious problems if you add it as a string with AddWithValue. No way. I suggest you to use a ORM instead of making your own database magic class.

Comment: basically all I am doing is adding to a list called textboxes with the name and text of the textboxes on the form or so I am trying.

Comment: @LarsTech this is the line in members class that I am using, nothing else. `public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> textBoxes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();`

Comment: I know.  But your "members" class also has a DBCommand object.  And you are adding parameter objects to it before you declare it.  If it's not throwing an error, then you are adding parameters to a command object you created somewhere else in your code.  You should have very few global objects in your code base.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @LarsTech not trying to reinvent the wheel, I'm just trying to dynamically add the values without having to type every single textbox.Text

Comment: But your sql table isn't dynamic.  You are getting very little benefit by trying to loop through your textboxes.  You don't have any mechanism that maps the textbox to the field.

Comment: and how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your table's columns' names are the same as your textboxes names:

```
     using (members.DBCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO members (" + String.Join(", ", members.textBoxes.Select(tb => tb.Key).ToArray()) + ")" +
              " VALUES(" +  String.Join(", ", members.textBoxes.Select(tb => "'" + tb.Value+ "'").ToArray()) +   ")", members.DBConnection))
```

Else and if the items of the list `textboxes` are added in the same order of your columns then try this:

```
using (members.DBCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO members (fullName, birthday, phoneNumber, address, email, status, anniversary)" +
                  " VALUES(" +  String.Join(", ", members.textBoxes.Select(tb => "@" + tb.Value).ToArray()) +   ")", members.DBConnection))
```

Comment: tb,Name and tb.Text are throwing an error saying there is no definition for name and no extension for name accepting a first argument of type `KeyValuePair<string,string>`

Comment: Are your table's columns' names the same as your textboxes' names ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are now spending more time for trying generate insert query automatically then if you have typed it manually.

For generating proper insert query you need loop column names and column values(read names of parameters).
You definitely should use `SqlParameters` for values

```
var columnNames = string.Join(", ", members.textBoxes.Select(m => m.Key));
var parameterNames = string.Join(", ", members.textBoxes.Select(m => $"@{m.Key}"));
var query = $"INSERT INTO members ({columnNames}) VALUES ({parameterNames})";

using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, members.DBConnection))
{
    foreach (var member in members.textBoxes)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{member.Key}", member.Value)
    }

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You can associate column names with textboxes by using `.Tag` property

```
textboxFullName.Tag = "fullName";
```

Then create key value pairs with column names as a key

```
foreach (var textbox in Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<TextBox>())
{
    var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(textbox.Tag.ToString(), textbox.Text);
    members.textBoxes.Add(pair);
}
```

Comment: I understand that but there are a lot of textboxes. that's all.

Comment: my table column names are different than the textboxes names

Comment: I gave you an example of how query can be generated with parameters. If names of the columns are hardcoded to the query, then what purpose of generating values automatically? If you add new column  - you will need to add textbox and update query anyway

Comment: it's all blank (the insert query). It's just INSERT INTO members () VALUES ()

Comment: @user2101411, that mean that collection `members.textBoxes` is empty.